# Error: Fatal error: Class 'Paypal\Api\Payer' not found

Tags: php, paypal

Tengo el siguiente problema:

Importé la librería de paypal (`paypal/rest-api-sdk-php`) con `composer`, pero me tira error el siguiente

> "error Fatal error: Class 'Paypal\Api\Payer' not found"

**Start.php**

```
<?php
// 1. Autoload the SDK Package. This will include all the files and classes to your autoloader
// Used for composer based installation
require __DIR__  . '/vendor/autoload.php';
// Use below for direct download installation
// require __DIR__  . '/PayPal-PHP-SDK/autoload.php';

$apiContext = new \PayPal\Rest\ApiContext(
    new \PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential(
        'hjkshkhkjkhjkjhaskjhdkjhasdjkhashdhegrfyrfyrfr',     // ClientID
        'hkshkahskjdhaskjhdkjahsdkjahskdjhakjshdkjashdkjahsdkjhaskjdhajkshdkjasd'      // ClientSecret
    )
);

$apiContext->setConfig([
 'mode'=>'sandbox',
 'http.ConnectionTimeOut'=>30,
 'log.LogEnabled'=>false,
 'log.FileName'=>'',
 'log.LogLevel'=>'FINE',
 'validation.level'=>'log'
]);
```

Y lo mando a traer desde un formulario con el action "checkout.php":

**Checkout.php**

```
<?php
use Paypal\Api\Payer;
use Paypal\Api\Item;

require 'start.php';

if (!isset($_POST['descripcion'], $_POST['precio'])) {
    die();
}

$descripcion = $_POST['descripcion'];
$precio = $_POST['precio'];

$total = $precio;

$payer = new Payer();
$payer->setPaymentMethod("paypal");

$item = new Item();
$item->setName($descripcion)
    ->setCurrency('MXN')
    ->setQuantity(1)
    ->setPrice($precio);
$itemList = new ItemList();
$itemList->setItems([$item]);
```

> Fatal error: Class 'Paypal\Api\Payer' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\pagos\checkout.php on line 22

Alguna idea?

Ya intente poniendo con `require`, `include`.

En la parte de **start.php** ya intente poniendo:

```
require __DIR__  . '/vendor/autoload.php'
require './vendor/autoload.php'
require 'vendor/autoload.php'
```

**Editado el 14/09/2014 Resuelto:**

Como no cargo `require __DIR__  . '/PayPal-PHP-SDK/autoload.php';` lo que hice fue el `require` desde la ubicación de la API:

```
require 'PayPal-PHP-SDK/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/lib/PayPal/Api/Payer.php';
require 'PayPal-PHP-SDK/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/lib/PayPal/Api/Item.php';
```

Saludos.

Comment: En start.php, no tienes un index.php? debe ser: include "./vendor/autoload.php"; trata y me dices si funciona.

Comment: añade esto : use PayPal\Api\ItemList; abajo de use Paypal\Api\Item;

Comment: Si has resuelto el problema, como ya han pasado más de 2 días, puedes poner como lo has resuelto como respuesta.

Comment: Ok "el asiduo" saludos.